# Spring Boot Not loading css files: Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: css, gradle, spring-boot, materialize, webjars

Spring boot app is not loading css files form materializecss library imported with Gradle

in my controller I have method that looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String home(){
    return "user/index";
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorator="layout/default">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initialscale= 1,
            maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Dodaj produkt</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row" layout:fragment="content">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the default.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initialscale= 1,
            maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Witaj w Thymeleaf</title>
    <link href="/webjars/materializecss/0.98.0/css/materialize.css"
          type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="nav-extended">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="/" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a th:href="@{/products}">Produkty</a></li>
            <li><a th:href="@{/categories}">Kategorie</a></li>
            <li><a th:href="@{/cart}">Koszyk</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
            <li><a th:href="@{/products}">Produkty</a></li>
            <li><a th:href="@{/categories}">Kategorie</a></li>
            <li><a th:href="@{/cart}">Koszyk</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div layout:fragment="content"></div>
<script src="/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/materializecss/0.98.0/js/materialize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".dropdown-button").dropdown();
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" layout:fragment="script"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting error

```
WARN 4520 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'GET' not supported
```

and css styles are not loaded

[css files not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNxQN.png)

I was trying to find solution but i couldn't find anything that match my problem

[EDIT]
I didn't do anything except creating another simple app to find out if those webjars will work in it. It was working so I restarted main app and problem is almost gone. Now the css files are loading properly, but I'm still getting warnings that request method 'GET' is not supported, although everything looks fine right now
[EDIT]
Still not working, in another app css file are loading and in my main app I'm getting 405 when I try access them

my whole MainController looks like this, there is no other method that is  mapped to "/"

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
    private ProductServiceImpl productsService;
    private CategoryService categoryService;
    private CartSession cartSession;

    @Autowired
    public MainController(ProductServiceImpl productService, CategoryService categoryService,
                          CartSession cartSession){
        this.productsService = productService;
        this.categoryService = categoryService;
        this.cartSession = cartSession;
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public List<CartItem> getCart(){
        return cartSession.toList();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String home(){
        return "user/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("products")
    public String products(Model model, @PageableDefault(size = 20) Pageable pageable, SearchForm searchForm,
                           SortingForm sortingForm){
        Page<Product> products = productsService.findAll(pageable);
        PageWrapper<Product> page = new PageWrapper<>(products, "/products");
        model.addAttribute("products", products);
        model.addAttribute("page", page);
        return "user/products";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "products", params = {"search"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String searchedProducts(Model model, @PageableDefault(size = 20) Pageable pageable, SearchForm searchForm,
                                   SortingForm sortingForm){
        Page<Product> products = productsService.searchByQuery(searchForm.getToFind(), pageable);
        PageWrapper<Product> page = new PageWrapper<>(products, "/products");
        model.addAttribute("products", products);
        model.addAttribute("page", page);
        return "user/products";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "products", params = {"sort"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String searchedProducts(Model model, @PageableDefault(size = 20) Pageable pageable,
                                   SortingForm sortingForm, SearchForm searchForm){
        Page<Product> products = productsService.getProductsOrdered(pageable, sortingForm.getOrderBy());
        PageWrapper<Product> page = new PageWrapper<>(products, "/products");
        model.addAttribute("products", products);
        model.addAttribute("page", page);
        return "user/products";
    }

    @RequestMapping("productPicture/{id}")
    public void getProductPicture(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("id")Long id) throws IOException {
        String image = productsService.findById(id).getImagePath();
        response.setHeader("Content-Type",
                URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(image));
        InputStream in = new FileSystemResource(image).getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }

    @RequestMapping("product/{id}")
    public String productInfo(@PathVariable(value = "id")Long id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("product", productsService.findById(id));
        return "user/product";
    }

}
```

Comment: can you provider your controller?

Comment: I have added it in question

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved

Reason why any of my webjars files or even files from resources directory weren't loading properly was another controller in which I had an error in this annotation

```
@RequestMapping(name = "/cart/updateProductQuantity", params="update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

I have changed it to this and it's working for me right now

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cart/updateProductQuantity", params="update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

If someone knows why this was the problem, please share it with me